# How to reference an unconventional column name in a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Reservation` class

```ruby
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :member
  has_one     :schedule, as: :schedulable, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessor :user_of_booking_id
```

How do I add a `has_many` relation that references `user_of_booking_id`?

```
<%= reservation_form.input :user_of_booking_id, label: reservation_label, collection: bookers_collection, input_html: { class: 'chosen-picker' }, wrapper: :default_form %>
```

Is there a way to use `user_of_booking_id` in `has_many` without changing my database?

Comment: You do realize that that the original post is still available through the edit history? Delete the question instead of just mangling it.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`alias_attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-alias_attribute) - not `attr_accessor`.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :member
  has_one     :schedule, as: :schedulable, dependent: :destroy

  # new_name, old_name
  alias_attribute :user_of_booking_id, :member_id 
end
```